# jquery "when + Then" is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery "when ,Then" to do some operations . I am using the doAddProcedure function to perform some calculations  . Am expecting a result like after executing the code in doAddProcedure function the control will return back to AddProcedures and then to the codes in Done section .But it was not working as expected. Also i am showing a loader to show during the  time of execution of the codes in doAddProcedure  section . The loader was not showing for the time taken to execute the codes in doAddProcedure. Please help me to fix the issue.Sorry for my English

This is my code

```
    var tot_codes = 0;   
    function doAddProcedure(thisval)
    {

        top.ShowAjaxLoader('Loading..');     
        var countval = $("#last_id").val();


          //My code block....
         return true;
    }  
    /**
     * Function to add procedures
     * @returns {undefined}
     */ 
    function AddProcedures(thisval)
    {
        $.when(doAddProcedure(thisval)).then(function(){        
          if (tot_codes > 0) {
              //setTimeout(function(){ 

                top.notification('successfully added the codes.');            
                //top.window.parent.document.getElementById('circularG').hide();
                window.parent.phFrntpayClosePopup();           
                //top.window.parent.document.getElementById("loaderHtml").style.display = "none";          
              //}, 3000); 

        } else {          
            top.notification('Please select atleast one code.');     
        }           
        }); 
    }

AddProcedures(thisval); // Calling main Function
```

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I reduced the code block.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you don't pass a Deferred or a Promise to the `when` then the `then`is executed immediately. Look at the jquery documentation for [When..Then](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

In your case you are treating the `when()` as if it were some sort of `if` condition that waits for `true` ... I suggest you read more about `Promise`, `Deferred` and then come back to the `when..then` logic or use the Promise.

You could of course use callback function like below :

```
doAddProcedure(thisVal,callbackFunc){
// do stuff
callbackFunc();
// If you wish to wait a moment (say 3 seconds here) before the callbackFunc() is called, and it is purely cosmetic, then comment the above and uncomment the below !
//setTimeout(callbackFunc, 3000);
}

myFunction = function(){        
          if (tot_codes > 0) {
              //setTimeout(function(){ 

                top.notification('successfully added the codes.');            
                //top.window.parent.document.getElementById('circularG').hide();
                window.parent.phFrntpayClosePopup();           
                //top.window.parent.document.getElementById("loaderHtml").style.display = "none";          
              //}, 3000); 

        } else {          
            top.notification('Please select atleast one code.');     
        }           
        };

function AddProcedures(thisval)
    {
        doAddProcedure(thisval, myFunction);
    }
```

Comment: I just took the above link but all the examples are for ajax. Can you give me a sample code like above . I am not well experienced in front end scripts.

Comment: I suggest that then you simply use a callback function to solve it as I mentioned  ... otherwise you end up implementing something you don't understand at all or might take a lot of reading before you get there .

Comment: I changed my code like you said above. But My loading image is not showing . It will show if i given return false just above top.notification('successfully added the codes.'); . This is the code used for hiding the loader.

Comment: What if it is indeed shown, but it is overwritten so fast that you simply don't see it .. add a timeout or something if that is the only concern ...

Comment: Codes in doaddprocedure  is for  appending some html elements selected in the popup to the parent html page.The popup is the contents loaded from an  iframe .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138246/discussion-between-exception-al-and-rejeesh-thampi).